# Making a hole on in a UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiwebview

I have a UIView on top of that I have a UIWebView . Now I need to create a hole in Hole in UIWebView to make the UIView visable from back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a mask over the `UIWebView`

```
// Create your mask layer
CALayer* maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,yourMaskWidth ,yourMaskHeight);
maskLayer.contents = (__bridge id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourMaskImage.png"] CGImage];

// Apply the mask to your uiview layer        
yourUIWebView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the `opaque` property of the `UIWebview` to `NO`.

Comment: In that case you'll need a combination of a transparent `UIWebView`, and areas of transparency within the content.